# PhantomJS Parse Error On Specific Sites

Tags: phantomjs

When I try to run the following extremely simple PhantomJS script, I get a parse error:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://compare.nissanusa.com/nissan_compare/NNAComparator/TrimSelect.jsp', function (status) {});
```

Anyone know why this could be happening? The error message is not helpful at all... It just says "Parse Error".

Could this be a bug in PhantomJS?

I am using PhantomJS version 1.9. I'm able to run the above script with other URLs, but for some reason certain URLs return a parse error...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because there is a javascript error on the web site `http://compare.nissanusa.com/nissan_compare/NNAComparator/TrimSelect.jsp`. `Parse Error` is not because of your code.

Phantomjs does not really loves js error when loading a page, that's why it's important to add an error handler.

To easily catch an error occured in a web page, whether it is a syntax error or other thrown exception, use [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html).

Here is a basic example :

```js
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
    if (trace && trace.length) {
        msgStack.push('TRACE:');
        trace.forEach(function(t) {
            msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function + '")' : ''));
        });
    }
    console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};
```